# Which of the following is false Statements.

Tags: number-theory

Which of the following statements is FALSE? There exist an integer $x$ such that :

$1.\quad x\equiv 23 \mod1000$ and $x\equiv45 \mod~6789.$

$2.\quad x\equiv 23 \mod1000$ and $x\equiv54 \mod~6789.$

$3.\quad x\equiv 32 \mod1000$ and $x\equiv54\mod~9876.$

$4.\quad x\equiv 32 \mod1000$ and $x\equiv44 \mod~9876.$

I don't know too much number theory . I am just learning number theory . According to me first and second options are incorrect as $\gcd(1000,6789)=1$ so by chinese remainder theorem solution will exist. Please provide me detailed solution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If "solution will exist", then why are these options incorrect???

Comment: its incorrect according to question...

Comment: a solution to the first one is 10876023

Answer (score 3):

**3rd Answer **

1. gcd(1000, 6789) = 1, 45-23 = 22, 1 divides 22 this implies there exist solution.
2. gcd(1000, 6789) = 1, 54-23 = 31, 1 divides 31 this implies there exist solution.
3. gcd(1000, 9876) = 4, 54-32 = 22, 4 does not divides 22 this implies there does not exist solution.
4. gcd(1000, 9876) = 4, 44-32 = 12, 4 divides 12 this implies there exist solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but i think it is the opposite, since their gcd is 1 there is always a solution for the first and second statements

1st statement is correct: x = 6789000 n+4087023 and n element Z

2nd statement is correct: x = 6789000 n+4216023 and n element Z

(thanks to wolfram alpha)

3rd statement is incorrect and i think it has to do something with 54 not being divisible by 4 but the other integers are

4th statement is correct: x = 8 (308625 n+139504) and n element Z is a solution